# Separate URL for each git branch in Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am looking into Cloud Run to host my new app, and I am wondering if it is possible to generate a separate URL for each git branch.
I use Netlify to host my other app. When it is connected to GitHub (or other VCS services), it builds the source code in a branch and deploy it to a URL that is specific to the branch.
Can it be done easily or do I have to write some logic?

Or do you think AWS amplify or some other services are of better fit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept of Cloud Run and URLs is quite simple:

`https://<service-name>-<project hash>.<region>.run.app`

If your project and region are the same for all the branches, you simply have to deploy a different service for each branch to get a different URL.

That was for Cloud Run. Now, I'm not sure that Netlify is compliant with Cloud Run. I found no documentation on this.

Comment: Perfect! Although Netlify automatically associates git branch with endpoint URL, the same thing can be achieved very easily on Cloud Run!

Answer (score 1):

This answer won't be directly useful to you but I think it's relevant and worth mentioning

The open source Knative API (and implementation actually exposes a "tag" feature while splitting the traffic between multiple revisions: https://github.com/knative/docs/blob/master/docs/serving/spec/knative-api-specification-1.0.md#traffictarget

This feature is not currently supported on Cloud Run fully managed, but it will be.

By tagging releases this way, you could define `tag: v1` and `tag: v2` in your traffic configuration, and you would get new  URLs like:

- https://v1-SERVICE_NAME...run.app
- https://v2-SERVICE_NAME...run.app

that directly go to these specific versions.

And the interesting thing is, these revisions you specified in the `traffic:` block of the Service object do not have to receive any traffic (you can say traffic `percentage: 0`) but it would still create a domain name like I showed above to the inactive revisions of your app.

So when Cloud Run fully-managed supports `tag` fields, you can actually achieve this, although it will be less out-of-the-box experience than Netlify.